# AWS policy error — Number of resources is greater than maximum allowed: But I have only 77 resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I am getting this error

```
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Number of resources, 507, is greater than maximum allowed, 500
```

but the catch here is that I have only 77 services defined in my serverless yml. What could be the other possibilities for this error to come up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a framework (such as serverless, or AWS SAM), it is possible that one resource in your template gets expanded to multiple resources in the resulting cloudformation template. This is probably what is happening here. A potential solution would be to use [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html).